# How to get the zk pages in the languages of the user after login

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, zk

I have a program in ZK using Spring-security. 
I have three languages for that webprogram. When a user login, I want to retrieve from the database his language and set the website in the website in the language of that user. I found a solution with putting this in the `doAfterCompose(Component comp)` controller of my page:

```
Locale currentLocale = (Locale) Executions.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(Attributes.PREFERRED_LOCALE);
        Locale userLocale = user.getLocale();
        if (currentLocale == null || !currentLocale.equals(userLocale)) {
            Executions.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute(Attributes.PREFERRED_LOCALE, user.getLocale());
            Executions.sendRedirect(null);
        }
```

But I don't think it is a good solution because when the user login, the page refresh twice. First it is shown in english and then it reload in the language of the user. This beheaviour is normal, because I put that in my code, but I want a better solution to retrieve the pages in the language of the logged user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
 Executions.getCurrent().getHeader("accept-language")
```